# Getting error while building ABP framework angular application

Tags: c#, angular, abp

I am facing some certain challenges while creating abp framework angular build. In my code there are two files,one consist app.component and the second one is consist module which have number of component, both files have ng-package and the module file have a reference in app-routing.module.

Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGgZm.png)

project structure

Angular
|
projects
|
dev-app (first file with app-component, ng-package, and angular json)
module  (second file with component and ng-package)

How can i prepare a build of it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.